# Buildozer packs an .apk, but it doesn't run

Tags: android, apk, emulation, kivy

I'm using Ubuntu 64 14.04 on VirtualBox, I've successfully made .apk-file using Buildozer, but when I start it on Android SDK emulator (running on Windows), it shows black screen with title at the top for a few seconds and then quits. (By the way, what emulator is better? This one is too slow.) How can I watch the cause of it?

**UPDATE:**

When I run `buildozer android run` on Ubuntu, it says:

```
# Application pushed.
# Application started.
```

And nothing happens. I haven't Android device and I don't know, should emulator run in this case. I'm running emulator separately on Windows, so I can't understand how to use logcat here.

**UPDATE:**

This is a part of log when I run my app.

```
I/ActivityManager(   65): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=
[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.test.mathcore/org.renp
y.android.PythonActivity } from pid 137
I/ActivityManager(   65): Start proc org.test.mathcore:python for activity org.t
est.mathcore/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity: pid=295 uid=10034 gids={1015}
I/dalvikvm(   65): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
W/ResourceType(  295): No package identifier when getting value for resource num
ber 0x00000000
V/python  (  295): metadata fullscreen is1
I/SDLSurface(  295): Surface will NOT be transparent
V/Python  (  295): Extracting private assets.
I/python  (  295): extracting libpymodules.so
D/libEGL  (  295): egl.cfg not found, using default config
I/ActivityManager(   65): Displayed org.test.mathcore/org.renpy.android.PythonAc
tivity: +4s216ms
D/libEGL  (  295): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
I/SDLSurface(  295): Choose egl configuration
I/SDLSurface(  295): Try to use graphics config R8G8B8A8S8
I/SDLSurface(  295): Try to use graphics config R5G6B5S8
E/SDLSurface(  295): Unable to find a correct surface for this device !
I/ARMAssembler(   65): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [
 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x4737b520:0x4737b6d8] in 1044006 ns
E/JavaBinder(  295): Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
E/JavaBinder(  295): Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
I/WindowManager(   65): WIN DEATH: Window{40801d10 org.test.mathcore/org.renpy.a
ndroid.PythonActivity paused=false}
I/ActivityManager(   65): Process org.test.mathcore:python (pid 295) has died.
I/WindowManager(   65): WIN DEATH: Window{40802e28 SurfaceView paused=false}
W/InputManagerService(   65): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notif
ication to pid 295 uid 10034
W/InputManagerService(   65): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: co
m.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40806910
D/dalvikvm(  137): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 79K, 51% free 2945K/5959K, external 1
1042K/12993K, paused 127ms
```

**UPDATE:**

[Full log](http://pastebin.com/wVw1xMb9).

Comment: to see the logs you can use http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: +1 for use logcat, it will show the error in your stdout (the normal python traceback, usually). For the emulator, mostly we test directly on devices since it's very easy - just plug it in and add 'deploy' to the buildozer command.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a relatively uninteresting part of the log.

Comment: @Henry, I've added full log.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using emulators, but you can do it like this:
First activate USB-debugging on your android phone.
Then connect it to the pc/laptop and run the following command in the terminal:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

then the app should appear on your phone screen...

Comment: I told I haven't Android device.

Comment: debug mode is the hint that helped me